# Bash script in container

Tags: shell-script, docker

How to execute a bash script in the docker container from the host such  that it should not get exited from the container  after execution of script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use bash as an interactive non-login shell with option `--rcfile` file.

MAN:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash
>   reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This
>   may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option
>   will force Bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
>   ~/.bashrc.

So use

```
bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bashrc; some_command')
```

as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-new-shell-then-give-control-back-to-user).

Comment: Thank you Egor. I could reach into the container from   host through the script file but commands are not getting executed in the container

Comment: What command do you use to start rontainer?

Answer (score 0):

Look at using docker exec along with -d for the detached flag i.e.

```
docker exec -d <containerid> /path/to/script
```